# What is the maximum number of tags a mob can have?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft 1.16.1, If you run this command two times: `/tag @p add test` you will get a message that says, Target either already has the tag or has too many tags.  So that means i know there is a limit in how many tags a mob can have at the same time but how high is that limit? Is it something i need to be worried for to hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to be worried. Look carefully:

> Target either **already has the tag** or has too many tags.

Here is what happens:

### First run

Minecraft adds the tag `test` to the player.

### Second run

Minecraft tries to add the tag `test` to the player but it already exists. So it throws the error.

---

I don't know the limit off-hand, but it should be more than you ever need.

Answer (score 2):

The limit in Java Edition is 1024 tags per entity.<sup>*</sup>

Note that a tag can only be added once. It either exists or it doesn't, the game doesn't count how many times it has been added. That's why you get an error if you try to add a tag more than once.

If you want numeric values you should use either [the scoreboard system](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard) or [NBT data](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/data).

---

* According to [the Wiki at the time this answer was written](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tag?oldid=2223464).